# How tu turn this function into a thunk react promise function (Updated)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am fetching data from the blockchain. Contract adresses in this case.
Once I have the adresses I fetch some info on each specific adresses and add a key=>value pair to the object. This is all working and I'm getting all the right data. However, once in the component, the newly added key=>value pair is no longer present. I think this is because the value added is a promised and the dispatch is not waiting on it. How can I fix this so the dispatch it done only once the promised is resolved.

```
const tokenStream = await exchange.getPastEvents('OtherToken', {fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'})
const allTokens = tokenStream.map((event) => event.returnValues)

console.log('ALL TOKEN DATA : ', allTokens)
allTokens.forEach( async element => {
 let symbol = await exchange.methods.getERCsymbol(element.tokenAddress).call()
 element.symbol = symbol
});
console.log('ALL TOKEN DATA AFTER : ',allTokens) // I see symbol 
dispatch(allTokensLoaded(allTokens))
```

Comment: your `getMarket ` seems async so inside it may be you can use `await  exchange.getPastEvents` as it returns promise

Comment: @HardikSatasiya Yes it's there sorry but it's only good to pass trough. If I take the array and do more request then modify the array the data is not sent to the UI. Only the original request. That's why I need Thunk. I do other request in my code.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya In other word the await and async are only good for the first request not the subsequent data manipulation

Comment: if you share us what are those `subsequent data manipulation` we can help you more, means if you have async function you can do multiple awaits as much as you like

Comment: I do some request on the network. by the time i get the answer the outpus is already it the UI

Comment: I tried so many thing i just cleaned it out back to my starting point.

Comment: hmm not sure without full code anybody can help :(

Comment: There is no full code since i'm trying to make it work. Anything i do with the data there is to late cause it's already sent to the UI.

Comment: The console might show it but not the UI

Comment: @HardikSatasiya This is what i'm trying to do. But the added symbol is not present once in my component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution would be to use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple async request/promise to finish, and also you are mixing `await` and `then`, as your main function is already `async` you can write it in more `neat and clean way` using `await` only.

```js
export const loadAllTokens = async (exchange, dispatch) => {
  const result = await exchange.getPastEvents('OtherToken', {fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'});
  const allTokens = result.map((event) => event.returnValues);

  await Promise.all(allTokens.map(async (element) => {
    const innerResult = await exchange.methods.getERCsymbol(element.tokenAddress).call();
    element.symbol = innerResult;
    element[2]= innerResult;
  }));

  dispatch(allTokensLoaded(allTokens));
}
```

its more clean and better to understand :).

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Could we have moved that promise all statement higher or i still need to wait on the first one to resolve?

Comment: `prmise.all` depends on `allTokens` and seems we are getting that from `exchange.getPastEvents` so we can not in this case, order need to be followed here

Answer (score 0):

They happens to be nested async request and this is how I fixed it

```
export const loadAllTokens = async (exchange, dispatch) => {
   await exchange.getPastEvents('OtherToken', {fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'}).then( async(result) => {
    const allTokens = result.map((event) => event.returnValues)
    let count = 0
    allTokens.forEach( async element => {
      await exchange.methods.getERCsymbol(element.tokenAddress).call().then( async(result) =>{
      element.symbol = result
      element[2]= result
      count += 1
      }).then( () => {
        if(count ===  allTokens.length){
          dispatch(allTokensLoaded(allTokens))
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```